# Why isn`t the image showing?

Tags: html, image

When I try to run the site in the browser, the image dosen`t show.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="no">
  <head>
    <title>Ferskvaregrossisten</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet type=text/css" href="stylesheetfgross.css">
  </head>

  <body>

  <header>
    <h1>Ferskvaregrossisten</h1>
    <img src="IMG_0342.JPG" alt="logo">
  </header>
```

Comment: Do you have the image in the same directory where you accessed the html file?

Comment: I believe so. @Dekel

Comment: Try to access it... check if it's there

Comment: By clicking on the file? Done, it is there.

Comment: no, open it in the browser, the same way you open your html file

Comment: Done, it`s showing in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Copied the url from the browser, the url was a little longer. Now it`s showing.  Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your image has duplicated suffix. If you're on a Mac, right click the image in your finder and open 'Get Info', if you're on a Windows, you can right click the image and click 'properties'. Double check the real name of the image, it might be 'IMG_0342.JPG.jpg'.

Answer (score 0):

there would be several reasons:

1.Wrong path name.

2.Wrong file name.

3.Wrong file Suffix.